# Mysql with Entity Framework migrate tool

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

As part of a CI implementation I would like to use the migrate tool that ships with Entity Framework 6 to run migrations (note I do not want to run them automatically).

I have the migrate tool in the bin folder of my site and run:

`migrate assembly_with_configuration_type.dll /startupconfigurationfile="path_to_web.config"`

However this gives me: `ERROR: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration' threw an exception.` The assembly that I specify in the command is NOT the MVC web application, but is an assembly from a referenced project within the web application.

Start of my configuration class:

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CustomDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());  
    }
}
```

The customdbcontext is a plain class that is resolved on app_start using `LocalIocManager.Resolve`. Not sure what's going on.